# Draw a single frame in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is a simple question I can't find in the [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) documentation.

How can I draw a simple frame in a scatter plot? In the example below, I have removed the ticks and labels. Now I just want that put to include a simple frame and define the thickness.

```js
var chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    // labels: names,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [{'x':0.1,'y':0.1},{'x':0.4,'y':0.4},{'x':0.8,'y':0.8}]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    title: {
        display: false,
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              display: true,
              gridLines: {
                  display : false
              },
              ticks: {
                  display: false,
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  max:1
              }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                  display : false
              },
              ticks: {
                  display: false,
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  max:1
              },
          }]
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could draw a border around the `canvas` by defining some CSS style.

```
<canvas id="chart" style="border: 2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Together with this, you need to make sure, the chart ground lines on x an y fit the limit of the canvas. This can be done by defining some minus [`padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) as follows:

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    left: -10,
    bottom: -10
  }
},
```

The last point is to completely hide your axes by defining `yAxes.display: false` and `xAxes.display: false`.

Please have a look at your amended code below

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    // labels: names,
    datasets: [{
      data: [{ 'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.1 }, { 'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.4 }, { 'x': 0.8, 'y': 0.8 }]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: -10,
        bottom: -10
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,     
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 1
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 1
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
style="border:1px solid #000000;"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" style="border: 2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it's not possible using the Chart.js API directly?